# Application for web development (silverlight) not debugging

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, silverlight, visual-studio-debugging

I am beginner to Visual Studio 2010 Express, I am trying to debug a C# web application using XML (as GUI buttons etc.) and using Silverlight. 
Before running the application i have Step Into and Step Over (which can be pressed, and it's color is in dark where as Step Out color is light and that can't be pressed). You can see the screenshot on [this link](http://prntscr.com/34ej6v).

And on clicking the Start Debugging button I don't have any option for attach process and it don't debug actually when i see on my break points it not at all debug. Now all Step Into and Step Over and Step Out, all are in light color and none can be pressed.Please see the screenshot on [this link](http://prntscr.com/34ekeq) also on clicking "Web" i get this see the link please  prntscr.com/34eya9

I am using Firefox Could that be a problem for not debugging ? But it is displaying the GUI i have created using xml and c#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

right click on the project, go to "properties", select "web" tab, scroll at the bottom, and you will find that under "debuggers" silverlight is not checked.

check that, and rebuild the solution.

this should then enable silverlight debugging.

Comment: this is the first thing i done. No i am not able to click on there (there color of that check is even light, Not dark) . please see this link to know more http://prntscr.com/34ex1l

Comment: thats because your application is running. stop it first.

Comment: @sDev "Attach to process" option is generally in "debug" option. Am i right ? It even don't show it please see this link (after clicking on "start debug") http://prntscr.com/34ezun

Comment: I am using firefox could that be a problem for debugging? Even it show the buttons on firefox which i have created using xml and c#.

Comment: Silverlight wont debug in any other browser

Comment: now how to set it to internet explorer ? I want to check if it work there or not ?

Comment: just set your default system browser to IE, and hit F5 in visual studio. the site should automatically open in IE.

Comment: if you dont want to change your default system browser, then just right click on one of your .aspx pages in the project, choose browse with, then select IE from the list and click set as default. When you will debug now, IE should be your default browser.

Comment: thanks i am installing it and will mark it answered as soon it works :)

Comment: @dev On installing  i have an error "IE cannot be installed on on window 7 service pack1". Which version should i try to install ?

Comment: Install it from Control Panel > Program and Features > Turn Windows features on or off

Comment: It's already checked in Dev. see http://prntscr.com/34fgrj may be i unisntalled it in past and now it don't work so what do you personally suggest is best suitable version for Window 7, 64 bit os ?

Comment: thats installed then ... try running this from run command: C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe

Comment: @Dev i IE worked and i installed Silver light(which was uggested by IE itself) but when i tried to run project now it gives http://prntscr.com/34fr5r .

Comment: and the best is could you please let me know how to set IE as default browser ?